# Битая кодировка в pdf

Tags: php, кодировка, pdf

Привет, подскажите пожалуйста как так получается, что в каком нибудь ридере pdf отображается нормально, но стоит скопировать кусок текста из pdf, он выглядит так:

`F!ÁÄÄÆ(ÈÉÂÃ`

Также и при выводе текста через php.

Comment: часто у pdf есть картинка и текст поверх. Видите вы картику и там нормальный текст. А копируете текст  - а он - не очень

Comment: На PHP какую библиотеку используете для генерации PDF?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте utf8_encode(), может поможет